# Expo dev client cannot connect to the dev server

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-dev-client

A development build that uses `expo-dev-client` and Expo Application Service seems to be having trouble connecting to the dev server.

The dev client app hangs on the splash screen after running `npx expo start --dev-client`. The JavaScript bundle process also doesn't start.

After a while, I get the error screen on the app saying that its request to connect to the dev client timed out.

```
There was a problem loading the project.

This development build encountered the following error:

Failed to load app from http://172.20.1.160:8081
with error: The request timed out.
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: Why this is a problem? Just use ```npx expo start —dev-client ```
(Here you can find an explanation: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/16360#issuecomment-1047958200)

Comment: @MichaelBahl I realized a type in my original post. I changed `npx expo run --dev-client` to `npx expo start --dev-client`.

The problem is that the application hangs on the splash screen and the development server doesn't start building JavaScript bundle. I'd like to know how to troubleshoot this and find the root cause.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `--tunnel` to the `expo start` comment solved the issue.

`npx expo start --dev-client --tunnel`

More information on "tunneling" at [this expo-cli doc page](https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#tunneling).

Comment: Hi have you found a solution that doesn't involve `--tunnel`? I'm running into exactly the same issue and would prefer not to tunnel, because it slows things down.

Comment: same issue with expo sdk 48. --tunnel works for me

Comment: I post an issue here, https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22668, it seems like the node version is the main factor of this issue

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue. I wasn't connected to my WiFi network which was causing the error.

Comment: this is a valid reason,

Answer (score 0):

expo sdk 49

```
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios
```

iOS simulator build install on simulator then run

```
npx expo start --dev-client
```